# WinSCP .NET assembly throwing "The winscp.exe executable was not found at location of the assembly" when installed to GAC for SSIS

Tags: ssis, gac, winscp, winscp-net

I have a package which downloads files from FTP using WinSCP which runs perfectly when I execute it locally. But we are facing issues when we run from the deployed version from SSIS DB Catalog. GAC registration already done for the .dll file.

Below is the error that we are getting.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting documentation on [Installing the WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install):

> **Installing**
>
> The package includes the assembly itself (`winscpnet.dll`) and a required dependency, WinSCP [executable](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) `winscp.exe`.
>
> The binaries interact with each other and must be kept in the same folder for the assembly to work. In rare situations this is not possible (e.g. **when [installing the assembly to GAC](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#gac)**), **make use of the [`Session.ExecutablePath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#executablepath) property to force the assembly to look for the `winscp.exe` in a different location.**